# fastest IN PROCESS technique for sharing memory and IPC in win32/C/C++

Tags: c, windows, dll, shared-memory

I'm writing a real time library which exports a standardized interface (VST) and is hosted by external applications.

The library must publish a table that is viewable by any thread in the same process (if it knows where to look) - to be clear, this table must be viewable by ALL dlls in the process space - if they know where to look.

Accessing the table must be fast. Virtual memory seems like overkill, and I've considered using a window handle (and I still may) to message pump, but I'd prefer an even faster method, if one is available.

Also, a shared data segment in the PE is something I'd like to avoid if possible. I think I'd almost rather use a window handle.

I'm not concerned with synchronization at the moment, I can handle that after the fact. I'd just like some suggestions for the fastest technique to publish the table within a process space.

Comment: Why would you want to use a message pump? You can easily use a global variable and hide it with some nice interface functions that your library exports. Can you elaborate a bit more on your requirements and  standardized interface (VST)?

Comment: Huh?  All memory within a process is accessible by all threads of that process.  If you need to share memory between separate processes, then use shared memory.

Comment: I'm a little concerned about what will happen when you start to be concerned with synchronization.

Comment: How exactly are you making a real-time library on an OS which is inherently not real-time?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confused. All threads in the same process share the same address space, so you don't need any form of IPC: if a thread knows the address of the table, it can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateFileMapping` and pass in `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` as the file handle.
This will create a named shared memory page(s) that is accessible by anyone who knows the name.

Don't be alarmed by the fact that MSDN docs say it's backed by the paging file - it will only go to disk in case your physical memory is exhausted, just like regular system memory.

In all regards, since it's supported by hardware MMU - it's identical to regular memory.